# Finding the center of gravity of an object that does not have equal distribution of mass

Tags: gravity, mass

NOTICE: I have very limited knowledge of physics so try not to confuse me, though I know it is inevitable.

Say I have a grid of squares, where a □ has 1g of mass, while a ■ has 5g of mass. If I create a random (but joined together) grid of these squares, how would I find the center of gravity of this shape? E.g:
[image: Example]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to take the first one as an example.  Assume that the square position corresponds to coordinates, so that first square is at x = 1, etc.  The center of mass is given by

$$ CM = \frac{\Sigma_i (m_i*x_i)}{\Sigma_i m_i} $$

For the first one this equation gives

$$CM=\frac{1*1+1*2+5*3+1*4}{1+1+5+1} = 22/8 =3.75 $$

Comment: While this answer is great, can I ask that you explain how I could do this from a 2D standpoint? As in, rather than there being a line of blocks, there is a whole shape, since I don't know how (or if) I could go from 1D to 2D.

Comment: @Ben If you replace $x_i$ with $\vec r_i$ to symbolize radius (that is, distance from the the center) then the formula works for a 2D system. Since radius is a vector this means that you must think about the direction to the point.

Comment: @Steeven Would this mean that, for example, all the blocks on top of the center have a positive radius, but those on the bottom have a negative radius, with the same thing for left and right blocks?

Comment: @Ben That's a way to look at it. But what then for those that do not lie directly above or below the center? It might be better to consider each vector by its components. And then you are perfectly right; all y-components pointing up are positive and all pointing down negative, when you sum them. Same for the x-components.

Comment: @Steeven To make sure the method in my head is correct, could you make me a simple example?

Comment: @Steeven Actually, no need, I tried it on a simple example and it seems to work perfectly! Now I have to convert that formula to program code...

Answer (score 0):

Assume the four squares are at locations 0, 1, 2, and 3. Assume the mass of each square is $M_1$, $M_2$, $M_3$, and $M_4$. If $x$ is the center of mass, then you can write the following equation:

$$(x-0)\times M_1 + (x-1) \times M_2 + (x-2) \times M_3 + (x-3) \times M_4 = 0$$

This is basically saying that if $x$ is the balance point on a teeter-totter, then the torques on the right balance the torques on the left. If you solve for $x$, you will have the location of the center of mass as a distance measured from the center of the left-most cube.

You can rearrange the equation as follows:

$$(M_1+M_2+M_3+M_4) \times x = 0 \times M_1 + 1 \times M_2 + 2 \times M_3 + 3 \times M_4$$

therefore:

$$x = (0 \times M_1 + 1 \times M_2 + 2 \times M_3 + 3 \times M_4)/(M_1+M_2+M_3+M_4)$$

Comment: Paul's answer is also correct, except that 22/8 = 2.75 (not 3.75), and he assumes the left-most square's position is 1, and I assume it's zero.  His math is also prettier.

Comment: Now your maths is just as pretty, maybe without the division fractions (If that's how you refer to them)

Answer (score -1):

Since you say that you have little knowledge of physics I'm going to assume that you're not very facile with algebra etc.,  the solution is to use the "Fermi" method.  Build the shape out of Legos or your favorite toy.  Then cut a square out of cardboard and fold it in half to form a tent.  Now balance the shape on the roof of the tent to find the center of mass.  Repeat for each axis.  This should be good to 10 or 20% with almost no effort.